# List と for文 を使ったコマンドの自動実行

Tags: python, python3

Python 3.6.7 で、Ciscoコマンドの自動実行処理についてコードを書いております。

[目的]
『Listに、実行したいコマンドを追記/削除して列挙する事で、その後の for文 で
　List上のコマンドを順次処理してくれる。』というコードを考えております。

[実際のコード]

```
command = ['ter len 0', 'show clock', 'show version', 'sh inventory', 'exit']
comlist =",".join(command+'\r\n')
for com_set in comlist:
    com_set = str.encode(com_set)
    ser.write(comlist)
```

[エラー内容]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l:/python/coltpython/prompt.py", line 115, in <module>
    comlist =",".join(command+'\r\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
PS L:\python>
```

そこで質問です。
listを何とかstrの並びにして、順次for文で処理できる様にする事は出来ないでしょうか？

ご教示の程、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この場合、for文を使う必要はなくて、コマンドセットを改行コードで join して serial port に書き込めば良いかと思います。`ser.write('\r\n'.join(command).encode())`

Answer (score 0):

わざわざ文字列にしなくても、リストのままその要素を順番に処理することができます。

```
commands = ['ter len 0', 'show clock', 'show version', 'sh inventory', 'exit']
for command in commands:
    # ここで command を使う
```

Comment: ご教示くださいましてありがとうございます。おかげで処理出来る様になりました。